# Could not connect to Snowflake backend after 1 attempt(s).l

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Could not connect to Snowflake backend after 1 attempt(s).Aborting
If the error message is unclear, enable logging using -o log_level=DEBUG and see the log to find out the cause. Contact support for further help.
Goodbye!

i tried every way in snowflake. i am trying to connect to snowfalke using snowsql

Comment: are you able to connect?

Answer (score 0):

Check your config file and all credentials were intact.

Comment: tried everyway but it is saying.

Comment: 250001 (n/a): Could not connect to Snowflake backend after 1 attempt(s).Aborting
If the error message is unclear, enable logging using -o log_level=DEBUG and see the log to find out the cause. Contact support for further help.
Goodbye!

Answer (score 0):

For me, this happened because earlier in my code I had set some proxies, something like:

```
os.environ['http_proxy'] = "http://my_proxy" 
os.environ['https_proxy'] =  "http://my_proxy"
```

Once I commented those out and reran the code, I was able to connect to Snowflake. If simply commenting out the os.environ proxy variables doesn't work, you could also try deleting them from your environment entirely

```
del os.environ['http_proxy']
del os.environ['https_proxy']
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have correct details in .snowsql/config file and then try following:

`snowsql -a <orgname>-<accountname> -u <username>`

For instance in my case if I check the snowflake url it is as below:

https://app.snowflake.com/prnvhwz/lmn25601/worksheets

Here, orgname = prnvhwz and accountname = lmn25601

So if you execute:

`snowsql -a prnvhwz-lmn25601 -u <username>`

It should work!!!